# Referencing an enclosing instance from an inner class

Tags: java

This is a knowledge/curiosity question only.

After several years in Java, this has only just struck me.

```
class Foo {

   class Bar{

      Foo.this.doSomething();

   }

}
```

When I look at `Foo.this`, I would assume that it's a static reference which obviously is not the case.

I know this is part of the Java spec, but exactly what is going on when you use `<Class>.this`?

Is it one of those "it just is" things?

Comment: @noob.  Please don't edit out the Android tag.  I only code using Java because I create Android apps.  This question has broad relevance to Android devs also.

Comment: Firstly, Bhesh Gurung is the one who removed the Android tag, not noob.  The fact that you happen to use android is irrelevant to the tagging.  I could just as easily tag this question as Windows if I happen to do my Java programming to create Windows apps.  Your question is not making use of any android-related functionality, so it doesn't warrent an android tag.  I've refrained from reverting your edit, but solely due to fear of a pointless edit war.

Comment: @Brian.  Well, it's all a little silly anyway, but if most Android devs also subscribed to the Java tag, I might agree with you.  Since they don't, and Android devs are a very significant group in the set of all Java devs, I respectfully disagree.  Thanks for leaving the edit.

Comment: @Brian.  Sorry, BTW, it was stupid of me to not check the edit history and apologies to noob.

Comment: @Simon: I suggest removing the *android* tag. As it stands, it creates the incorrect impression that this Java question is specific to Android, and thus it gets filtered out when looking for general Java questions while excluding Android-specific questions. Android developers who want to learn about Java in general are free to search for the *java* tag.

Comment: This is definately not Android specific, so that Android tag must be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know this is part of the Java spec, but exactly what is going on when you use .this?

It just refers to a "hidden" field within `Bar`. It's easiest to see this by decompiling. You'll see that there's a `Bar` constructor taking a reference to an instance of `Foo`. That reference is stored in a field, and then when you use `Foo.this`, it just accesses that field. So assuming you'd put your `Foo.this.doSomething()` into a `someMethod` call, your code is similar to:

```
class Foo {

   static class Bar {
      private final Foo $foo;

      Bar(Foo foo) {
          this.$foo = foo;
      }    

      public void someMethod() {
          $foo.doSomething();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I never knew that.  It's all so clear when laid out like this ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet Nice answer but if this is what it looks like after being decompiled, how does it work when the inner class has a parameterized constructor?

Comment: @MarkW: Why don't you try it to find out? :) (It'll just add an extra parameter to the list that you've written...)