# Enclosing outer class instance reference of an inner class from outside inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

Each inner class instance "lives" in an instance of its outer class. The question is - how to refer to the instance of the outer class given the instance of the inner class when the inner class has no member pointing to its outer-class instance?

Eg:  In the following, the method `check()` provides the desired reference to the `Outer` class instance from within `Inner` for the ultimate use.

```
public class Outer {

int cnt = 0; 

class Inner {
    boolean check() {
    return cnt==10;
    }

}

public static void stuff(Outer.Inner in) {
    if (in.check()) 
    // if (<cnt value of its enclosing Outer class instance is 10>) 
    //      do sth here
    ;
}
}
```

However - assume the method `check()` didn't exist.

```
public class Outer {

int cnt = 0; 

class Inner {

}

public static void stuff(Outer.Inner in) {
    if (<cnt value of its enclosing Outer class instance is 10>) 
    //      do sth here
    ;
}
}
```

Then, what is the syntax to refer to the outer-class instance of `Outer.Inner in` so that one can refer to `cnt` member of that instance and go from there **without changing the `Inner` class code in any way?**

Note: seen [Reference outer class instance from inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253355/reference-outer-class-instance-from-inner-class) and [How to refer to Enclosing class from Inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059951/how-to-refer-to-enclosing-class-from-inner-class) among some other discussions. I'm looking to reach the outer class instance NOT from within the inner class instance itself.

TIA.

//----------------

EDIT:

boldfaced one crucial part of the clue.

Comment: `cnt` is an instance variable so isn't it just `outer.cnt`?

Comment: @markspace - well - that's the Q. you first gotta get that `outer` so that you can refer to its member `cnt`.

Comment: @Gab - it is duplicate. thx for the ref.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this without help.  You'll need to add a method to return the enclosing instance.

[Referencing an enclosing instance from an inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985058/referencing-an-enclosing-instance-from-an-inner-class)

```
public class Outer {

  int cnt = 0; 

  class Inner {
    boolean check() {
      return cnt==10;
    }
    Outer getOuter() { return Outer.this; }    
  }

  public static void stuff(Outer.Inner in) {
    int count = in.getOuter().cnt;
  }
}
```